# php imagecreatefrompng

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I have an image I created in Macromedia (Adobe) Fireworks.  I exported it as a PNG32, with a transparent background.  It's fine when I call the image to the browser normally:

```
<img src="myimage.png" />
```

However, when I use php to display the image, I have aliasing problems.  The edges of the image get pixelated.  And for those who want to know what the image is, it's a cartoon face, with a border of about 2 pixels - outlining the character.

I've played around with my code, but the same thing happens.

Here's what I've coded:

```
<?php
$img = 'myimage.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Without actually uploading a sample of the image, which I'll do if necessary, does someone understand why borders would get choppy?

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? Does the same thing happen in other browsers?

Comment: Just checking: This is sample code, is it? You're actually going to do something more with `$img`, right? Or do you just want to output the file as-is using PHP?

Comment: I'm curious, if you're not doing anything to the image, why not just link to it directly or if you have to, use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: That's a good question.  I've tested it in these: FF, IE, Chrome.

Comment: And yes, I do have more plans with the code.  I intend to merge other images on top of the face.  It's actually practice for another website I need to work on, apparel related.  Thought I'd work on anything I got my hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this to see if it helps:

```
<?php
$img = 'myimage.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img);
// enables alpha channel
imagealphablending($img, true); // setting alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($img, true); // save alphablending setting (important)
```

Comment: My pleasure friend. Happy coding.